# Notice: Undefined variable: referenceTableData in /home/u/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Declaration/SchemaBuilder.php

Tags: magento2.3.7

hello I have a module I need to install and after uploading my module to my server and making the command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

I get this error

Notice: Undefined index: mageworx_optiontemplates_group_option in /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Declaration/SchemaBuilder.php on line 352

and the code line in 352

$referenceTableData = $this->tablesData[$constraintData['referenceTable']];

Comment: check the module patch data file, there will be an attribute which have the options taking from the php class. Either Remove that attribute or verify the code and name.